# Bootstrap/Rails - Adding 'close' to flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, alert

i've been trying to work this out myself and not have to ask but I can't seem to find a solution.

I have a flash notice working perfectly in my app: 
application.html.erb excerpt:

```
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag :div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
```

..my question is, is there a way of adding the 'close' bootstrap feature within the above code?..

i.e:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

..but including it within my <%=  %>

(it obviously doesn't need to be the 'warning' class as above, this was just copied from bootstrap as an example)

Thanks in advance!!

Justin

---

@MattBricston
..i'm struggling to grasp the key == :notice ? 'success' : 'danger' line, would it only work for 'success', and 'danger' bootstrap alerts?..is it just a matter or adding : 'warning' : 'info' etc??...

Thanks again, really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% alert_class = case key
                   when :notice then "success"
                   when :alert then "danger"
                   else key
                   end %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{alert_class}" do %>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <%= value %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Keep in mind that:

- Rails flash keys are `:notice` and `:alert`, but Bootstrap's classes are `success` and `danger`, so you have to do some conversion.
- Make sure to also include Bootstrap's JavaScript on the page so that the × button actually works.

**Update for clarification:**

The flash keys in Rails can be whatever you want. So you can use `:success`, `:info`, `:warning` in your controller and use those directly as Bootstrap classes in your markup without any conversion to get the desired style.

However, in my experience, some third-party gems for Rails (including Devise, I think) use `:notice` and `:alert` for their flash message keys. Therefore it is probably still a good idea to translate those two into the appropriate Bootstrap class names, as in my example.

Comment: I updated my answer to use a `case` statement for handling arbitrary flash keys like `:info`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0.  Add this to your application layout right before the `<%= yield%>`

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
      <div class="alert alert-success">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <%= flash[:notice]%>
      </div>
    <% elsif flash[:error]%>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <%= flash[:error]%>
      </div>
     <% elsif flash[:alert] %>
      <div class="alert alert-warning">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
          <%= flash[:alert]%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Bootstrap 5

In application_helper.rb | _notices.html.erb is in the comment below

```
def bootstrap_class_for(flash_type)
{
  success: "alert-success",
  error: "alert-danger",
  alert: "alert-warning",
  notice: "alert-info"
}.stringify_keys[flash_type.to_s] || flash_type.to_s
```

end

Comment: <% flash.each do |msg_type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(msg_type) %> alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"> 
    <%= message %>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>
<% end %>

Answer (score -1):

```html
  <div class="alert alert-info"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"> </span> 
    <strong> Sorry....! </strong> Something went wrong. 
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"> &times; </button>
</div>
```

This worked for me.... Please try it once.